# Python get clustered data-Hierachical Clustering

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I used following python script to do a hierarchical clustering and print the dendogram. Please consider I'm new to Data-mining.

```
import numpy as np
import distance
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage

mat = np.array([[ 0. , 1. , 3.  ,0. ,2.  ,3.  ,1.],
 [ 1. , 0. , 3. , 1.,  1. , 2. , 2.],
 [ 3.,  3. , 0.,  3. , 3.,  3. , 4.],
 [ 0. , 1. , 3.,  0. , 2. , 3.,  1.],
 [ 2. , 1.,  3. , 2.,  0. , 1.,  3.],
 [ 3. , 2.,  3. , 3. , 1. , 0. , 3.],
 [ 1. , 2.,  4. , 1. , 3.,  3. , 0.]])

linkage_matrix = linkage(mat, "single")

dendrogram(linkage_matrix,
           color_threshold=1,
           truncate_mode='lastp',
           distance_sort='ascending')

plt.show()
```

Following is the dendogram that I have got. I need to print the clusters and the data that belongs to each cluster?

```
cluster1 4,5
cluster2 ..,..
cluster3 ..,..
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `scipy.cluster.hierarchy` documentation

> (by running linkage...) A 4 by (n-1) matrix Z is returned. At the i-th iteration, clusters with indices Z[i, 0] and Z[i, 1] are combined to form cluster n + i. A cluster with an index less than n corresponds to one of the n original observations. The distance between clusters Z[i, 0] and Z[i, 1] is given by Z[i, 2]. The fourth value Z[i, 3] represents the number of original observations in the newly formed cluster.

That means, we can iterate over `linkage_matrix` and find the actual nodes combined to form new cluster. Here is a small for loop to do that

```
n = len(mat)
cluster_dict = dict()
for i in range(0, 6):
    new_cluster_id = n+i
    old_cluster_id_0 = linkage_matrix[i, 0]
    old_cluster_id_1 = linkage_matrix[i, 1]
    combined_ids = list()
    if old_cluster_id_0 in cluster_dict:
        combined_ids += cluster_dict[old_cluster_id_0]
        del cluster_dict[old_cluster_id_0]
    else:
        combined_ids += [old_cluster_id_0]
    if old_cluster_id_1 in cluster_dict:
        combined_ids += cluster_dict[old_cluster_id_1]
        del cluster_dict[old_cluster_id_1]
    else:
        combined_ids += [old_cluster_id_1]
    cluster_dict[new_cluster_id] = combined_ids
    print cluster_dict
```

The code creates a dictionary of cluster id to the nodes contained in that cluster. In every iteration, it combines two nodes in `linakge_matrix[i, 0]` and `linkage_matrix[i, 1]` into a new node. Finally, it prints the running clusters in each iteration. The output is

```
{7: [0.0, 3.0]}
{8: [4.0, 5.0], 7: [0.0, 3.0]}
{8: [4.0, 5.0], 9: [6.0, 0.0, 3.0]}
{8: [4.0, 5.0], 10: [1.0, 6.0, 0.0, 3.0]}
{11: [4.0, 5.0, 1.0, 6.0, 0.0, 3.0]}
{12: [2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 1.0, 6.0, 0.0, 3.0]}
```

(The cluster ids start with 7, original rows are indexed 0 to 6). Note that the ids not in dictionary form their own cluster. For example, row `2.0` forms its own cluster in iteration 2. You can get final set of clusters by stopping early depending on your stopping criteria.

I can stop at iteration 3, (3rd row of output) and then my clusters will be:

```
cluster 8: {4, 5}
cluster 9: {6, 0, 3}
cluster 1: {1}
cluster 2: {2}
```

Comment: Thanks very much,Nice work :) ,I'm trying to improve this more.